# Parse and twitter callback URL

Tags: ios, api, twitter, parse-platform, twitter-oauth

I'm following the documentation here and I'm stuck on step #3
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#twitterusers/iOS

I'm trying to get my app to have a "Sign in with Twitter" thing, and I don't really know if this step is necessary. What does it mean by callback URL?

Do I have to do some type of extra coding for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the callback URL would be used if you were using a webview to sign in with Twitter. Essentially, the flow would be something like this:
 - User is on your site/app and clicks to login with Twitter
 - They get sent to Twitter to login
 - Twitter lets them log in and shoots them back to your website/app

The last step is where a callback URL comes into play. It lets Twitter know where to send users after they sign in. In the tutorial, you aren't displaying all of this to the user, so it isn't really important to have URL there. He mentions that Twitter requires one, so you can throw anything in there (www.google.com, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The callback URL is a required only if you're performing web-based OAuth. As you are not performing web base oAuth you don't need it. But if asked put a valid one. like your own web site address. Hope this helps.. :)